# Compute stats for several columns at the same time using sapply

Tags: r, statistics, sapply

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   Placebo    High  Medium      Low
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1  0.0400  -0.04    0.0100  0.0100 
2  0.04     0      -0.0100  0.04   
3  0.0200  -0.1    -0.05   -0.0200 
4  0.03    -0.0200  0.03   -0.00700
5 -0.00500 -0.0100  0.0200  0.0100 
6  0.0300  -0.0100 NA      NA
```

You could get the cohensD for two of the columns using the cohen.d() function from the effsize package:

```
df <- data.frame(Placebo = c(0.0400, 0.04, 0.0200, 0.03, -0.00500, 0.0300),
                 Low = c(-0.04, 0, -0.1, -0.0200,  -0.0100, -0.0100),
                 Medium = c(0.0100, -0.0100, -0.05, 0.03,  0.0200, NA ),
                 High = c(0.0100, 0.04, -0.0200, -0.00700, 0.0100, NA))

library(effsize)
cohen.d(as.vector(na.omit(df$Placebo)), as.vector(na.omit(df$High)))
```

Interestingly enough, I'm getting the following error with this code:

**Error in data[, group] : incorrect number of dimensions**

However, I would like to create a function that allows you to obtain all the cohensd between one of the columns and the rest of them.

In order to get the cohensD of all columns against the Placebo we would use something like:

```
sapply(df, function(i) cohen.d(pull(df, as.vector(na.omit(!!Placebo))), as.vector(na.omit(i))))
```

But I'm not sure this would work anyway.

Edit: I don't want to erase the full row, as cohens d can be computed for different length vectors. Ideally, I would like to get the stat with the NA removed for each column independetly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to remove the `NA` on each of the columns separately by creating a logical index along with 'Placebo'

```
library(dplyr)
library(effsize)
df %>%   
  summarise(across(Low:High, ~ list({
             i1 <- complete.cases(Placebo)& complete.cases(.x)
             cohen.d(Placebo[i1], .x[i1])})))
```

---

Or if we want to use `lapply/sapply`, loop over the columns other than Placebo

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
          x1 <- na.omit(cbind(df$Placebo, x))
          cohen.d(x1[,1], x1[,2])
})
```

-output

```
$Low

Cohen's d

d estimate: 1.947312 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
    lower     upper 
0.3854929 3.5091319 


$Medium

Cohen's d

d estimate: 0.9622504 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
     lower      upper 
-0.5782851  2.5027860 


$High

Cohen's d

d estimate: 0.8884639 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
     lower      upper 
-0.6402419  2.4171697
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I know this option exists, however you miss one of the values, as you delete the full row. CohenD can be computed with different size vectors. In any case, I'm also getting this error. `Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(Low:High, ~list(cohen.d(Placebo, .x)))`.
x invalid 'row.names' length`

Comment: @RoyBatty thanks, you are right.  I noticed that was a buggy option once i wrote it.  Updated

Comment: thanks for you answer. However, using the lapply method I get  `Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length `

Comment: @RoyBatty is this error based on the same example you posted?

Comment: yes it is the same as the one posted @akrun

Comment: @RoyBatty I tested again, it is giving me the same output without any error

Comment: @RoyBatty try on a fresh R session, maybe your env got corrupted